# Embed HTML5 games in iframe with ability to switch to full screen mode on different domain

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, embed, fullscreen

I'm trying to enable full screen support for a game embedded from archive.org.

Example of embed code is:

```
<iframe src="https://archive.org/embed/DukeNukem" width="560" height="384" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Full screen mode is available on the archive.org game page itself - see the actual game page and full screen button (upper right):

https://archive.org/details/DukeNukem

What I would like to have is the ability to switch the embedded iframe and game canvas to full screen mode from a remote website.

I have tried various Javascript and have been able to make the iframe go into full screen mode, but the game canvas itself stays the same size with each of js implementation I have tried resulting in large full screen iframe with small game viewport and lots of black space. If possible, I would like the actual game canvas to resize similar to how the full screen button works on archive.org.

I was hoping to find a creative way to be able to enable full screen mode on a different domain with the embedded html5 iframe game.

I think it may be possible with using Adobe Flash, but would prefer to avoid Flash if possible since support is getting faded out everywhere. Another thought I had was to actually zoom the users browser to the original game canvas size with a button press to get the user in a quasi-full-screen mode. Since the resolution of this game is so low anyways, I don't think it would result in much loss of graphic quality. Just not sure of the code to actually make this zoomed, quasi-full-screen mode possible to dynamically resize to users screen size and center on the iframe / game canvas. Of course is there is a better way, you can think of to enable full screen mode on the embed, I would love to hear your creative ideas!

Thank you in advance for your help - it is most appreciated!! If nothing else, my question will let you experience a bit of nostalgia if you are old enough to remember Duke Nukem!!

Comment: It is possible that they restricted it. If I set the iframe width and height to the fullscreen values it is larger, covering all iframe - but if you press PLAY the game is rendered on the host server, delivering low-res result to the iframe.

Comment: yes it is quite frusturating, I have been trying out different js etc all day to find a solution, but still have not been able to acheive full screen experience. Best i am able to do is to manually zoom browser after game loads in iframe. Wondering if there is a way to automaticlly zoom the users browser to create this quasi-full-screen-mode? Anything is better than tiny window it loads in now - even just zooming browser window creates much better play enviornment. If I could create something that at least gets the size substantially larger or close to full screen it would be improvement.

Comment: even after the game canvas loads on archive.org, you can press the full-screen button to maximize it. Something simliar would be amazing if I could get it working with the embeded iframe.

Comment: if you add width:100% to the #canvasholder, which is the div od the loaded document, it actually fills 100% of the iframe - however, because of the cross-origin policy it cannot be done by JS :|

Answer (score -1):

```
//try this peace of code 

//do not forget to change the src in the iframe tag
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>full screen iframe</title> 
        <style type="text/css"> 
            html { 
                overflow: auto; 
            } 
            html, 
            body, 
            div, 
            iframe { 
                margin: 0px; 
                padding: 0px; 
                height: 100%; 
                border: none; 
            } 
            iframe { 
                display: block; 
                width: 100%; 
                border: none; 
                overflow-y: auto; 
                overflow-x: hidden; 
            } 
        </style> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
    <iframe src="" frameborder="0"
    marginheight="0"
    marginwidth="0"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    scrolling="auto"></iframe>
    </body> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you add some explanation to show how this will solve the problem in question, code-only answers are not encouraged..